# C# Cannot Delete File - System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, file-io, process

I am running a separate process that minimizes a folder of javascript files. This process creates a new file for each of the js files with "_min.js" appended to it. The next step is to delete the old js files (the ones without "_min.js"). For some reason File.Delete cannot delete these files.

It would appear that some process still has a handle on these files. I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException exception when I attempt the delete. I have sufficient privileges to this folder.  Can someone tell me what I am overlooking?

I am running the process several times in this loop.

```
 foreach (var fileInfo in jsFiles)
            {
                var outFileName = fileInfo.FullName.Replace(".js", "_min.js");

                var compressorPath = "\"C:\\Dev\\Team Interactive Tools\\trunk\\Infrastructure\\MsBuild\\lib\\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar\"";
               StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("-jar " + compressorPath + " ");
               stringBuilder.Append("\"" + fileInfo.FullName + "\"");
               stringBuilder.Append(" -o " + "\"" + outFileName + "\"");

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java\"";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = stringBuilder.ToString();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.Start();

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Then I try to remove the orginals:

```
   private void RemoveOrginalJs(FileInfo[] files)
    {
        foreach (var fileInfo in files)
        {
                File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
        }
    }
```

I am tried Process.close() after each process run but it makes no differance.

Comment: No more feedback from your side. Is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the tool that you are starting, but waiting for its completion somehow seems the right thing to do:

```
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the threads still have the file locked?  Do you wait for them to finish before you try and delete?

Answer (score 0):

Try Process.Kill() and delete afterwards.
Further you have to check if the script isn't running in another process aswell. To determinate this, try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).